# When creating an array initlializer why dont you have to type in new?

Tags: java, arrays

So for a standard array I understand that it is declared an assigned as follows.

```
    int array[]=new array[10];
```

However, for an array initalizer it is declared to multiple values as shown below, my question is why do we not need to type in new when creating an array initalizer?

```
    int array[]={1,2,3,12,131,3213,12,3,213,213,12,321,3,213,23,2,23132};
```

Comment: The second example is assignment and initialization.

Comment: that is because the compiler initializes the array at compile time

Comment: I still dont understand, can you supply more detail?

Comment: Because there is syntactic sugar to transform your second example into `int array[]=new int[] {1,2,3,12,131,3213,12,3,213,213,12,321,3,213,23,2,23132};` (if you examine the bytecode, you'll see they're identical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the runtime evaluation of array creation expression, if there are no dimension expressions, then there must be an array initializer. A newly allocated array will be initialized with the values provided by the array initializer, which happens internally. The value of the array initializer becomes the value of the array creation expression, which is an Object and is referenced by the variable initialized to. This can mostly be attributed to the design of the language.

Check this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1 for more information